# Choosing highest number in vector and knowing its position in R

Tags: r, max

I have a vector in R:

```
y=c(-29.900900, 5.728916, 35.234331,  11.854811,  61.309519,  50.432798, -27.654741,  21.413622, -10.805339, -37.504199)
```

I would like to select the highest number using for example `max(y)`.

Then it gives me `61.309519`.

BUT in addition I would like to know the position i.e. that its the `5th` element in the vector.

Is there any way to do this? I'm ok with using other data formats eg. `matrix` or `data.frame`

Answer (score 8):

```
which.max()
```

function will return the index of first maximum element. This might be important when you have more than one maximum in vector.

Comment: or `which(y==max(y))` if you want tied maxima.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned using matrices,
`which(mymatrix == max(mymatrix), arr.ind=TRUE)`  will locate the element by row and column.